# mysql-How to get sum of total hours of project and total hours of activities from below table

Tags: mysql

Table:team_activity

```
     act_id | act_dt    | act_activity   | act_total_duration
        1   |2017-03-03 | 2 i.e project  | 00:35:00
        2   |2017-03-03 | 2 i.e project  | 04:00:00
        3   |2017-03-03 | 1 i.e activity | 01:30:00
        4   |2017-03-03 | 2 i.e activity | 00:35:00
        5   |2017-03-04 | 2 i.e project  | 00:35:00
        6   |2017-03-04 | 2 i.e project  | 04:00:00
        7   |2017-03-04 | 1 i.e activity | 01:30:00
        8   |2017-03-04 | 2 i.e activity | 00:35:00
```

How to get sum of total hours of project  and total hours of activities where act_dt will be `act_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW()`

How to get sum of total hours of project  and total hours of activities where act_dt will be

the result i want is

```
act_dt     | total activity hours | Total project hours
2017-03-03 | 01:30:00             | 05:05:00
2017-03-04 | 01:30:00             | 06:00:00

SELECT *
      ,sum((TIME_TO_SEC(team_activity. act_total_duration) / 60))/60 as total_hours 
FROM team_activity 
where act_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() 
and act_usr_id=27 
and act_activity=1 
GROUP BY act_dt 
union 
SELECT *
      ,sum((TIME_TO_SEC(team_activity. act_total_duration) / 60))/60 as total_hours 
FROM team_activity 
where act_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() 
and act_usr_id=27 
and act_activity=2 
GROUP BY act_dt
```

Comment: Tell us what have you tried to do

Comment: i want sum of total hours of project and total hours of activities from current day to 7 days previous day .

Comment: Let us see the code you have tried to write

Comment: @VaishaliKasar it would be helpful if you could specify the type for column `act_total_duration `.

Comment: the datatype of column act_total_duration is time

Comment: SELECT *, sum((TIME_TO_SEC(team_activity. act_total_duration) / 60))/60 as total_hours FROM `team_activity` where act_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() and act_usr_id=27 and act_activity=1 GROUP BY act_dt
union
SELECT *, sum((TIME_TO_SEC(team_activity. act_total_duration) / 60))/60 as total_hours FROM `team_activity` where act_dt BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() and act_usr_id=27 and act_activity=2 GROUP BY act_dt

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't understand how the result set relates to the data set. Perhaps you meant "2 i.e. project"? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)